# How to define "duplicate" Android APKs?

Tags: android, security, machine-learning

I have downloaded a lot of Android APKs with **different hashes**, and after doing **reverse engineering**, I found that lots of APKs have exactly the same occurrences of API calls, among 145 calls in Android Level 17. (Personally, I think there is little chance for two different samples have the same API calls)

I used machine learning methods to classify the APK samples, but I do not know how to deal with the **"duplicates"** mentioned above.

Should I treat those APKs as different samples? Or **remove the "duplicates"** and then do the classification? With the "duplicates", the results will be better.

Is there any definition of **"duplicate" Android APK samples** in Android or in Cybersecurity field? Do **different hashes** mean different samples?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Honestly this question is vague. "Duplicate" is whatever you define it to be. You also don't define what you describe as a 'API' call. Support library and common third-party libraries could be in your sample set but as a App produce different results.

Comment: No, there is no definition. Different hashes don't mean different apk (especially if it's been reverse engineered foe redistribution so the package is changed)

Comment: @Morrison Chang: 
Our API call is Android level 17 standard package name: https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html. So you mean that there is no official definition of "Duplicated" Android APK, right?

Comment: @Zoe:
Could you explain "reverse engineered for redistribution so the package is changed" more clearly? Thanks!

Comment: Correct, only in the case of the Play Store each app is required to have a different package name: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package but that doesn't mean that two distinct apps could use the same code but have cosmetic difference (sports team news apps by same publisher) or as @hang12 is trying to explain I could take an existing app, decompile and change its package and put it in the store for sale. Your questions imply a lack of research into piracy issues on Android. Please do more research. Come back to SO when you have specific problem.

Comment: @hang12 de-compiling and changing the package names in the manifest and the actual paths, then re-build and package into a new apk with the same content, but a different package name. That will change the hash even though they are the same

Comment: Thank you very much, guys. You solved my question and it really helps a lot!